# How to use GnuPG with --passphrase?

Tags: bash, gnupg

I want to write a script that will run `gpg` a file called "file" with the passphrase "test".

Normally, when I use `gpg`, I usually just run `gpg -c file` and it asks me for the passphrase. But since I want this script to do everything on its own, I would like to provide the passphrase as part of the command.

Now when I try to use: `gpg -c file --passphrase test`, it outputs:

> usage: gpg [options] --symmetric [filename]

Which seams like it wants me to use `gpg --passphrase test --symmetric file`. But if I do that, it pops up a dialog asking me for the passphrase to use; which is not what I want.

How do I do set up the arguments correctly?

Answer (score 8):

In GnuPG, options must preced commands, thus the `--passphrase` option must come before `--symmetric`.

Regarding the pin entry window, that pops up anyway (although you use `--passphrase`), you're probably already using GnuPG 2, which requires `--batch` to be used together with `--passphrase`. From the man pages:

```
--passphrase string
    Use string as the passphrase. This can only be used if only one
    passphrase is supplied. Obviously, this is of very questionable
    security on a multi-user system. Don't  use this option if you
    can avoid it.  Note that this passphrase is only used if the
    option --batch has also been given.  This is different from
    GnuPG version 1.x.
```

Be aware that on multi user systems all other users will be able to read your command line, and thus also the passphrase while GnuPG is executed. Better use one of the other `--passphrase-*` options instead to read from a file or pipe.

Comment: What you're saying is that my order of the `--passphrase` and `--symmetric` arguments were actually correct, but I was only missing the `--batch` argument? Because that didn't work for me. I've tried to add `--batch` both before and after, just in case. Also, I don't how to check if what I'm using is GPG 2, but the part that you've pasted that says `Note that this passphrase is only used if the option --batch has also been given.` does not exist in my `man` page.

Comment: What operating system/distribution are you using? `gpg --version` should give information on the GnuPG version you're using. Do you have a `gpg2` binary?

Comment: I am using Xubuntu 14.04., the version of `gpg` is 1.4.16. Inspired by your comments, I found out that gpg2 is being developed separately, so I installed it and tried it out, but it complains that `no valid OpenPGP data found. processing message failed: Unknown system error`

Comment: Jens you're super awesome and answer lots of questions w/great answers, but you're wrong on one point: "options must precede commands, thus the --passphrase option must come before --symmetric." Not true at all.

Comment: @rsaw: You're partially right -- for `--symmetric` and `--passphrase`, the order does not seem to be relevant, but try to `--export` and define `--armor` afterwards. Generally, options must precede commands, which is also the order defined in the man pages.

Comment: @ImNotMike Using GnuPG 1 (`gpg` on your machine) you should not be required to use `--batch`. You might have enforced use of `gpg-agent` in your `gpg.conf`, and @rsaw's solution might be the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

Using `--pinentry-mode loopback` works with `--passphrase` & `--passphrase-[file/fd]`, and will let you enter new info, in case of filename conflicts for example:

```
File 'xyz.gpg' exists. Overwrite? (y/N)n
Enter new filename: xyz2.gpg
```

unlike `--batch` that will quickly fail, saying `...failed: File exists`

---

If you had originally added the verbose option (`-v`) first, you should have seen something like:

```
$ gpg -v -c file --pinentry-mode loopback --passphrase-file=passfile
gpg: Note: '--pinentry-mode' is not considered an option
gpg: Note: '--passphrase-file=passfile' is not considered an option
usage: gpg [options] --symmetric [filename]
```

indicating pretty clearly that it didn't like something about putting `-c` (`--symmetric`) first.

---

I consider gpg2's behaviour of ignoring `--passphrase` options unless accompanied by `--batch` as a bug.

Comment: Thanks, this helped when attempting to use `--default-new-key-algo` with `--quick-gen-key` and getting the "not considered an option" error. Put `--default-new-key-algo "rsa3072/cert,sign+rsa3072/encr"` first and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

If `gpg --version` reports v2, you need to add the `--batch` option.

Based on the syntax output you're probably using v1, in which case you want:

```
gpg --passphrase PASS -c --no-use-agent FILE
```

Note that the order of options is not important; however, any file needs to be the last argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

`gpg --passphrase hello -c --no-symkey-cache --cipher-algo AES256 --batch basic.c`

Also, the use of batch is not a bug, it was written in documentation [here](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg24/gpg.1.html):

[screenshot from docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuHDn.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).